# Prevent UINavigationController from popping on double tap of UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` in the root of my storyboard with three tabs. One of the tab is used to display the user information. I have set this tab to transition to the register/login page if the user has not registered. But the `ViewController` gets popped(and corrupts the `Navigation Bar`) when I double tap the tab icon. I  cannot use the modal transition as it hides the `TabBarController`. What is the best solution to solve this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "corrupts the Navigation Bar"?

Comment: The Navigation Bar displays the name of both the View Controllers. Also the following messages on Xcode `nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar` and `Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'shouldSelectViewController' delegate of TabViewConroller to check if the selected viewController is same as the clicked one and skip it accordingly.

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
       if(viewController == tabBarController.selectedViewController)
       {
            return NO;
       }
  }
```

Comment: I have created a CustomTabBarController as a subclass of `UITabBarController`.Added the above method to the CustomTabBarController. Set the ViewControllers of that tab as `UITabBarControllerDelegate`. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you set the delegate for your `UITTabBarController`?

Comment: Where do I set the delegate? In the `ViewController` or the `CustomTabViewController`.

Comment: I have a `CustomTabViewController` with three tabs as the root view of the app. The first tabs ViewController `UserViewController` navigates to `LoginViewController` unless the user is logged in. I don't want the `LoginViewController` or any of its subsequent ViewControllers to pop back to `UserViewController`.

Comment: CustomTabBarController *customTabBar = [[CustomTabBarController alloc] init]; customTabBar.delegate = self;

Comment: Nope. Still the same issue.